# Error SSHing to Elastic MapReduce JobFlow on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-map-reduce

When following the tutorial instructions for connecting to my JobFlow in EMR, I type following:

```
 ./elastic-mapreduce --jobflow j-3FLVMX9CYE5L6 --ssh
```

and get this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

I'm already able to run other elastic-mapreduce commands just fine to create flows etc, so I'm assuming there's security settings required on the actual master instance for the flow, but nothing in the tutorial explains how to configure this (after all, I need to SSH into it to do the configuration in the first place!)

Answer (score 3):

I found that I need to login as user "hadoop" using the EC2 keypair, and not any of the regular suspects (ec2-user, root, etc.) Like:

```
ssh -i privatekey.pem hadoop@masternode
```

Hope this is useful to someone.

Comment: Yes, the user name is important to avoid "Permission denied" error

Comment: Thanks! It's been a while since I've needed to SSH in and I'd completely forgotten about that.

Answer (score 2):

Ok now I feel sheepish: I was using the Amazon CloudFront keypair from the my initial account setup rather than keypair associated with my account for accessing EC2 instances, accessible from EC2 > Network & Security > Key Pairs in the AWS Management Console.

Answer (score 0):

The command "ssh -i privatekey.pem hadoop@masternode" worked great. The user "hadoop" must be used for "ec2 elastic mapreduce".